# A question about extending group actions to maps.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, equivariant-maps

It is known that an action $\alpha: G \times M \rightarrow M$ induces for each group element $g \in G$ a transformation on $M$, $T_g : M \rightarrow M.$

Now what is done to *extend* this action to $\mathcal{F}(M):= \{f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ is to define a transformation $\mathbb{T}_g : \mathcal{F}(M) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(M)$ by $\mathbb{T}_gf = f'$ with

$$f'(T_g(x)) = f(x) \, \,.$$

Why the above thing is defined in such a way? Also why do we define it to take as input $T_g(x)$?

I mean, of course we have that $T_g : M \rightarrow M$ is an *automorphism*, hence any $x \in M$ can be written as $x = T_g(x')$ for some $x' \in M$, but I simply don't understand why the above definition is formalized in that way.

Also, an equivalent (why?) definition, would be stating:

$$\mathbb{T}_gf(x') = f(T_{g^{-1}}(x')) \, \, \forall x' \in M .$$

This second one actually makes a bit more sense to me, in light of $\mathbb{T}_g$, but **why** do we take $g^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer the second question first. If $G$ acts on $M$ *from the left*, then it acts on $\mathcal F(M)$ from the right. If you want to define an action from the left, i.e.,

$$\forall x \in M, \ \forall f \in \mathcal F(M), \ \forall g,h \in G \colon \quad (\mathbb T_{gh} f)(x) \stackrel{!}= (\mathbb T_g (\mathbb T_h f))(x).$$

Hence, if you "define" $(\mathbb T_gf)(x) = f(T_{g}(x))$, then the above equation reads

$$f(T_{gh}x) = f(T_h T_g x).$$

Since $T_{gh} = T_g T_h$, this is only correct if $G$ is Abelian. In other words: you get an action from the right. Sometimes one wants to write it as an action from the left, and thus one takes the inverse.

Now for the other questions. If $f'(T_g x) = f(x)$ and $f' = \mathbb T_g f$ by definition, then $f'(x) = f(T_{g^{-1}} x)$, which is the second version you stated.

As for the question why everything is defined as it is: well, because we get an action in this case.

Comment: Thanks, but could you work out a bit more why if $g$ acts on $M$ from the *left*, then it acts on $\mathcal{F}(M)$ from the *right*? I think that's one of the main points that I'm missing.

Comment: I mean, I proved it. Applying $\mathbb T_g$ to a function $f$ means "plugging in $T_g x$ instead of $x$". So $(\mathbb T_{gh} f)(x) = f(T_{gh}x)$, but $(\mathbb T_g (\mathbb T_h f))(x) = f(T_h T_g x)$.
You can account for this problem in two ways: either you define the action on $\mathcal F(M)$ an an action on the right (i.e., write $(f \mathbb T_g)(x) := f(T_g x)$ instead), or apply $T_{g^{-1}}$ instead of $T_g$ so that the elements get reversed.

Comment: So by defining the right action $(f\mathbb{T}_g)(x):= f(T_gx)$ we would get that $(f\mathbb{T}_g(\mathbb{T}_h))(x) = f(T_gT_hx)$? Sorry for insisting but I just want to fix this crucial point in my mind.

Comment: Yes, exactly. :)

Comment: But why do we get that in the case of right action? >.<

Comment: I mean, just calculate: consider the map $\tilde f := (f \mathbb T_g)$. Then, by definition, $(\tilde f \mathbb T_h)(x) = \tilde f(T_h x)$. Now, using the definition of $\tilde f$, you obtain that $\tilde f(T_h x) = (f \mathbb T_g)(T_h x) = f(T_g (T_h x))$, et voilà.